# Creating grouped categories with str_detect and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

**Question**

I'm looking at creating custom groups for a category (`Type`). I'm able to do so 
using `str_detect` and `mutate` from `dplyr`. However, is there an easier way to do the grouping? The `ifelse` statement in `mutate` seems to be clunky and requires lots of typing.

Thank you!

**Reproducible Example**

```
data <- data.frame('Type' = c("Organ Failure", "Drowning", "Coronary Disease", "Accident"), "No" = c(3, 1, 2, 4))

              Type No
1    Organ Failure  3
2         Drowning  1
3 Coronary Disease  2
4         Accident  4
```

**Expected Output**

```
              Type No  Grouped Type
1    Organ Failure  3 Health Issues
2         Drowning  1      Accident
3 Coronary Disease  2 Health Issues
4         Accident  4      Accident
```

**Code used to produce above output**

```
data %>% mutate('Grouped Type' = ifelse(str_detect(data$Type, 'Organ|Coronary'), "Health Issues", 
                                        ifelse(str_detect(data$Type, 'Drown|Accident'), "Accident", 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is less typing but you can try `case_when` which is more cleaner and easy to understand in my opinion.

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
   mutate(`Grouped Type` = case_when(
           str_detect(Type, 'Organ|Coronary') ~ "Health Issues",
           str_detect(Type, 'Drown|Accident') ~ "Accident", 
           TRUE ~ NA_character_))

#              Type No  Grouped Type
#1    Organ Failure  3 Health Issues
#2         Drowning  1      Accident
#3 Coronary Disease  2 Health Issues
#4         Accident  4      Accident
```

Also no need to use `$` inside `mutate`.

Comment: could you please share with me what is `TRUE ~ NA_character_` in `case when?

Comment: @Javier it means if none of the conditions match above we want it to assign `NA` value.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fuzzyjoin` to do this instead of having multiple `ifelse`.  Create a key/value dataset and then join with `regex_left_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
keydat <- data.frame(Type = c("Organ", "Coronary", "Drown", "Accident"), 
      Grouped_Type = c("Health Issues", "Health Issues", "Accident", "Accident"))
regex_left_join(data, keydat) %>% 
        select(Type = Type.x, No, Grouped_Type)
#            Type No  Grouped_Type
#1    Organ Failure  3 Health Issues
#2         Drowning  1      Accident
#3 Coronary Disease  2 Health Issues
#4         Accident  4      Accident
```